# How to do android screen sharing

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, screen-capture, screensharing

The Android new api android L has screen capturing and sharing. I figure out how the screen capturing works by using MediaProjectionManager and VirtualDisplay api. But I coulden't figure out how to share what has been captured on my screen. Does anyone has a snip code or tutorial that shows how this is achieved?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: [Check this](https://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but that's a third party library API. Do you have Android native API code snippet instead?